# JavaScript animation freezes on client’s IE 9, but not mine. Why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I just coded an all HTML/CSS/JS christmas card for a client. I have tested it on multiple stations under all major browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE9/10).

On the clients machine, all the machines at his office, under IE9 (version 9.0.8112, same as mine), the animation breaks and the whole thing freezes. On all the machines I've tested the animation on, everything works flawlessly.

Everything also works flawlessly under all other browsers, on my stations and on his stations.

I cannot reproduce what he's experiencing on his machines, which makes it extra hard for me to debug. Also, his machines are mostly high-end stations and all are running the latest updates. The only thing I can see is different between his machines and mine is that his are all "PCs" and I run Windows 7 via BootCamp on iMacs and MacBook Pros.

Since I can't reproduce the issue, I have no idea where to start looking. What we are seeing on his machines is a complete screen freeze. All animation stops and we can't click on anything after the freeze happens. The freezing always happens at the same moment. There's "glitches" (which show a sequence of rapidly changing images) happening at set moments, and the screen completely freezes after the first.

Here's a link to the card: http://grouperegiscote.com/noel-2012/

Any ideas where I could start looking? Thank you!

Comment: All I can imagine is not enough RAM on the host machine. Good work BTW. Tres bien!

Comment: Thanks! He's experienced this issue even on machines with 8 and 16 GB of RAM.

Comment: All I can suggest is putting in some logging and determine which instruction is jamming things up, then see if you can re-factor that piece of code. Works well on my Win7 machine.

Comment: It's always freezing at the exact same moment, so finding the piece of code responsible for it should be feasible. However, I'm throwing a lot of images in the browser at the same time, so I'M thinking maybe it's something with that, where there's too many images present on the screen at once and everything just jams.

My problem still is that I have no way of replicating the problem. If only I was experiencing the same thing here, I could debug it.

Comment: Try using smaller (file-size) images and see what you get. Your code seems fine.

Comment: File size didn't do it. However, I did find the culprit. I caught the following error "DOM Exception: INVALID_STATE_ERR (11)", which seems to be related to an audio file written as an <audio> object. The error is caught when I'm executing a line of code which tries to set the audio file's time to 0 "document.getElementById('wind-2').currentTime = 0;".

Comment: Good catch. Not image related at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. Now I'm trying to understand why this error pops-up on specific random machines.

Comment: @BrunoCloutier: tricky one. Did you ever find out? One thing I wondered was whether your or your’s client’s computer’s IE 9 was switching into compatibility mode without you noticing?

Comment: Tested on my IE9 on IE9 standards mode and works okay. On any other document mode (IE8, quicks etc) it does not go past the loading screen. One thing you should try see is that there's a lot of working done. Maybe IE9's garbage collector isn't going so well. Check Chrome's Ram Profile ( http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/541/21uj.png ). Each time it goes down it's GarbageCollector working. If you want to force IE's GC to work at a time you want (after an animation, perhaps), use this: `if (typeof(CollectGarbage) === "function") { CollectGarbage(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation IE9 does not support animations. Maybe you have IE9 with IE10 support (turned on)?